# Annoying Sonata Admin Behaviour

Tags: doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have gone through this problem before but cannot remember how I fixed it, I guess it's been a long day.

I have a field that is nullable in my doctrine definition but is rendered as required on the Sonata Admin entry form. I don't want to turn off HTML validation therefore I am looking for a solution to get sonata admin to render the fields correctly.

I have tried to google but I have not been lucky. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the required option to false in the `configureFormFields` function of your entities admin class?

This is an example of one of my classes, where I use it to set it explicitly to `true`:

```
class MenuAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name', null, [])
            ->add('renderSubPages', null, [])
            ->add(
                'pages', 'sonata_type_model', [
                    'class' => 'ApplicationSonataPageBundle:Page',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'required' => true,
                    'multiple' => true
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

You could try setting the option in your class like this:

```
class EntityAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('yourField', null, ['required' => false ]);
    }
}
```